# Eclipse kepler release keyboard mapping issue in Mac

Tags: eclipse, osx-mountain-lion, eclipse-kepler

I started using Eclipse Kepler and I am not sure if that is at fault or some other change caused it.   Strangely * is treated as a meta character (Shift-8).  To get * to be printed I have to use Option-Shift-8.

For example import is bound to Shift-8 I which essentially causes the editor to be useless.

Choosing between editors did not help

I am using Macbook pro running 10.8.3

Answer (score 1):

Key bindings are stored in the **.metadata** directory which can be found in your workspace.

I solved this issue by going to my workspace directory and opening the file

```
.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi
```

Look for **SHIFT+8** and remove or comment out the enclosing **<bindings/>** element (I found two in my configuration).

Answer (score 0):

I have seen something similar.

I used Kepler with an old workspace, so some of my settings may have affected the defaults.

I got around the problem via the Keys preference page, where I simply used "Restore Command" for the offending key bindings.

Comment: Thanks,  I tried restore command but it did not help.  So, I decided to create a new workspace and import the projects there.   That fixed it.   Not sure what the real issue is.